# Android AChartEngine - Unable to change textColor in pie chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using aChartEngine to draw a pie chart .I need to change each text color of pie slice .Is there any possible way to achieve this .Any link would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant set each colors different for that u have to edit the library

Put these functions in **DefaultRenderer**

```
 private int[] mLabelsColors = {TEXT_COLOR};

public int[] getLabelsColors() {
    return mLabelsColors;
  }

 public void setLabelsColors(int[] col) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLabelsColors = col;
  }
```

and in **PieChart** do something like this but be careful about size of array

```
  if(i==0)
      drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY,
          shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColors()[0],
          paint, true, false);
      if(i==1)
        drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY,
            shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColors()[1],
            paint, true, false);

      if(i==2)
        drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY,
            shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColors()[2],
            paint, true, false);

      if(i==3)
        drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY,
            shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColors()[3],
            paint, true, false);
```

And where u are creating chard use

```
int Col[] ={Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE,Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN,Color.RED};

    mRenderer.setLabelsColors(Col);
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html

in the Class DefaultRenderer there is a method setLabelsColor(int color) but it changes the whole labels color, so i think you should try to edit it in the library source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did .

I edited the aChartEngine code base from http://achartengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ . I made a few changes to drawLabel(...) method to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an array of colors as mentioned in the following [link](http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/07/pie-charts-in-android-using-achartengine_25.html)